# How to determine if the inserted CD is an Audio CD?

Tags: c++, windows

With [GetLogicalDrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364972%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939%28VS.85%29.aspx), I can enumerate all the CD-ROM drives on my Windows machine.

How can I then tell which of them contain Audio CDs (as opposed to Data CDs or DVDs)?

Comment: There's also more interesting question of what would you do with combined disks, which include both audio and computer data (such disks do exist)?

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp I know [Weird Al's "Running with scissors"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_with_Scissors_%28album%29) does that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SimpleAudioCD.aspx

> The data stored on CDs is determined
>   in sectors. A "normal" CD-sector takes
>   2048 bytes (2KB) of size. Something
>   special about audio-CDs is, that their
>   audio-data is stored in sectors of
>   2352 bytes of size. That is because
>   one sector should store 1/75 of one
>   second of audio-data. One second needs
>   176400 bytes, so 1/75 needs 2352
>   bytes.

That implies, to me at least, that if the sector-size is 2352, it's an audio CD.  But as Eugene says in his comment, what if it is both?  NFI. :)

Comment: These requirements are part of the [Red Book Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Book_%28audio_CD_standard%29)